# Apart from Temperature / Speed , are there other changes when change of state of matter occurs?

Tags: forces, dimensional-analysis, states-of-matter

Apart from Temperature / Speed , are there other changes when change of state of matter occurs? 
Link to Wikipedia [State of matter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_of_matter) 
I want to add - Zero (0) Tag - but I don't have high enough score to create it. This tag is not related with the number of changes.

Comment: Temperature does not change during a first-order phase tranistion. I'm unclear what you are asking.

Answer (score 1):

“Phase changes” are a substantially richer subject than solid/liquid/gas/plasma.  Consider this phase diagram for water, which shows at least fifteen different phases. The solid phases have different crystal structures, different symmetries, and different properties like density and heat capacity. Note that at temperatures beyond the “critical point” near 650K, the phase change between liquid and vapor becomes second-order, which means the liquid and vapor “states” are not really distinct from each other.

> [image: Phase diagram of water.svg]
> By [Cmglee](//commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/User:Cmglee) - Own work, [CC BY-SA 3.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0), [Link](https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?curid=14939155)

Answer (score 0):

Density is perhaps the most obvious answer.

Answer (score 0):

What about the change from normal conduction to superconduction? Or the changes occurring in the formation of a Bose-Einstein condensate? It's the rule, not the exception, that other changes than speed and temperature occur.